# Checking If Word Is English Python

Tags: python, list

So, I am doing a project where I have a list with english words and want it to check the word i write is in the list and tell me if it's in english or not, I have no idea how to do this but It's what i'm supposed to do so I am asking for your help

```
text = open("dict.txt","r")
#Opens the dict.txt file I have and reads it

word = input("Type a word to check if it's english.")
#Type in a word to check if is english or not

if(word in text == true):
print(word, "Is in English.")
elif(word in text == false):
print(word, "Is not in English.")
#Check if word is true or false in the dict.txt and print if it is english or not.
```

Comment: You need to format your question

Comment: In python, it's `True` and `False` with capitals.

Comment: Sorry I always had some kind of error while trying it so I didn't know what to do, thanks for correcting it for me.

Comment: That's a first solution thanks for pointing that out @Will

Comment: The code still doesn't work But a later problem was fixed tho which is great!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `text` is a file object, which you first need to read from somehow. You could, for example, read them into a set (because of O(1) lookup times):

```
with open("dict.txt", "r") as f:
    text = {line.strip() for line in f}  # set comprehension

word = input("Type a word to check if it's english.")
if word in text:
    print(word, "Is in English.")
else:
    print(word, "Is not in English.")
```

As someone with a background in NLP: Trying to *actually* test whether a word is valid English is more complicated than you might think. With a big enough dictionary (that also contains inflected forms) you should have a high accuracy though.

Answer (score 2):

### For All Linux/Unix Users

If your OS uses the Linux kernel, there is a simple way to get all the words from the English/American dictionary. In the directory /usr/share/dict you have a words file. There is also a more specific american-english and british-english files. These contain all of the words in that specific language. You can access this throughout every programming language which is why I thought you might want to know about this.

Now, for python specific users, the python code below should assign the list words to have the value of every single word:

```
import re
file = open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r")
words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  file.read()).split()

def is_word(word):
    return word.lower() in words

is_word("tarts") ## Returns true
is_word("jwiefjiojrfiorj") ## Returns False
```

Hope this helps!!!